# How to replace the use of tmpnam() in the following code snippet

Tags: c, linux

I fully understand that `tmpnam` has been deprecated and would like to remove it from a function in an existing file that prevents me from building the project. However, since I am not familiar with it and am unable to experiment with it, I am not sure how best to replicate this functionality.

```
if ((myfileName = tmpnam(NULL)) == NULL) { return APP_ERROR }
```

I read the information on [tmpnam here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tmpnam.3.html) but the best I can come up with is to use something like:

```
if (tmpnam_r == NULL) { return APP_ERROR }
```

However, since I cannot compile with `tmpnam` and am unfamiliar with the code in question, I am not confident in properly capturing the original intent.

As best as I can tell, this appears to be testing if the file exists, and if not, simply returns an error, as the next step consists of copying content into `myfileName`, which should presumably exist following the above check.

Comment: Hi, you can use [`tmpnam_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/tmpnam) which is a safer version of this function.

Comment: The man-page for `tmpnam` recommends to use `mkstemp` or `tmpfile`

Comment: @IronMan `tmpnam_s()` is an optional function, part of the C standard's Annex K.  Effectively only Microsoft implemented it.  It being "safer" is a matter of debate. It being non-portable is not.

Comment: @AndrewHenle aren't Microsoft's `*_s` functions actually different from the ones in Annex K that nobody uses?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons [Yes, they are.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm)  However, I don't have any offhand knowledge of whether or not Microsoft's `tmpnam_s()` implementation follows [Annex K](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K) or not, so I left that out of my initial comment.

Comment: @VillageIdiot What is the platform(s) this code applies to?  Windows?  POSIX?  What's the usage?  Creating a temp file using `open()`?  Or `fopen()`?  How the result is used makes a large difference identifying and implementing  any replacement.

Comment: VillageIdiot, you have the start of a good question here.  Make it better with answers to @AndrewHenle [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57879137/how-to-replace-the-use-of-tmpnam-in-the-following-code-snippet#comment102182979_57879137)

Comment: @AndrewHenle I have updated the question with platform (linux) and some information around what this is used for (verifying the presence of a file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with [`tmpnam()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.4.4) is that it generates a name that is unique and does not exist when it returns, but that name is not guaranteed to be unique by the time you use it in a call to [`fopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html) (or [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html)).

The key feature of the [`mkstemp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkstemp.html) function is that it creates and opens a file with the new name, so that there isn't a TOCTOU (time of check, time of use) vulnerability. This cuts down the avenues for security risks.

Code designed to use `tmpnam()` usually needs a file name, so using [`tmpfile()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tmpfile.html) is usually not an option; it doesn't provide a way to find the file name.  If you don't need the file name then using `tmpfile()` works well and is Standard C, so it is widely available.

The specific case of `tmpnam()` and `tmpnam_s()` is interesting.  Although `tmpnam_s()` avoids some string-related problems, it does not change the behaviour of `tmpnam()` in the way that causes the security problems addressed by `mkstemp()`.  So, independent of the portability issues that arise from attempting to use `tmpnam_s()` (or any of the other `*_s()` functions from Annex K of the C11 or C18 standards), it doesn't fix the problem that causes `tmpnam()` to be deprecated.

You can arrange to use `mkstemp()` instead of `tmpnam()` and close the file descriptor before continuing with the other code:

```
tmpnam(name);             // Replace this

int fd = mkstemp(name);   // With this…
if (fd >= 0)
    close(fd);
```

It's not great, but it does ensure the file is created, which reduces the security vulnerabilities a bit, but not as much as using the file descriptor directly.  You could (should) wrap that into a function.

Note that the `mkstemp()` returns a file descriptor; if you want a file stream, you can use [`fdopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fdopen.html) to create a file stream from the file descriptor.  And if that fails, you probably want to remove the file (with [`remove()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/remove.html) or [`unlink()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/unlink.html)).

So, that gives you a need for `fmkstemp()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* mkstemp() */
#include <unistd.h>     /* close() */

extern FILE *fmkstemp(char *name);   /* Add to a convenient header file */

FILE *fmkstemp(char *name)
{
    int fd = mkstemp(name);
    FILE *fp = 0;
    if (fd >= 0)
    {
        fp = fdopen(fd, "w+");
        if (fp == 0)
        {
            close(fd);
            unlink(name);
        }
    }
    return(fp);
}
```

Note that after you've used `fmkstemp()`, you use `fclose()` to close the file stream (and, behind the scenes, that closes the file descriptor).

Don't forget to remove the temporary file before exit.  That's where a function registered with [`atexit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atexit.html) or one of its variants can be useful.